# Tensorflow estimator issue with datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm having a strange issue with TF estimators and trying to use tf.Dataset in my input function.

First off, my model looks like this:

```
    model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_column,
        hidden_units=[hidden_layers, hidden_layers],
        n_classes=n_classes)
```

and my feature colum is like this

```
    my_feature_column = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='image', shape=[32, 32, 3])]
```

Now, if I train like this, it all works fine and the training runs in a couple of seconds:

```
    model.train(
        input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            dict({'image':X_train}),
            y_train,
            shuffle=True),
        steps=nb_epoch)
```

But when I try to add in tf.Datasets in the input function, it takes forever to run:

```
def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'image':features}, labels))
    return dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size).repeat()

model.train(
    input_fn=lambda:input_fn(X_train, y_train, batch_size),
    steps=nb_epoch)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please? It should be identical, right?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: welcome! Have you referred the [input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#summary_of_best_practices)? You can try things like using prefetch for example as shown there. You can aslo set the [reshuffle_each_iteration](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) parameter to False in shuffle, if you do not want to shuffle your data every time it is repeated. Maybe these improvements can help. Also if you could shuffle and repeat your data using the fused op, it might also lead to a better performance!

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is repeating infinitely and there's no default maximum number of iterations, so tensorflow does not know when to stop.

Replace the line which says `return dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size).repeat()` with something like  `return dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(batch_size).repeat(10)`, which will train for 10 epochs, and you'll be fine.